# Power analysis for assessing performance of a binomial classification model

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, model-evaluation, statistical-power

I'm looking to perform third-party assessment of the false-positive rate of a video classification algorithm. I am feeding unlabeled video through a given classification algorithm and need to assess it for false-positives, the hard part is that there is so much resulting classified video it would take months for me to watch all of it. I'd like to perform a power analysis to only look at a sample of the video and specify the FP rate at a given CI/precision.

To make things simple, let's say the algorithm flags video sequences that have at least one cat in it. I'm looking to evaluate the frequency of false positives for all the new data. So I have tagged all the video that my algorithm has identified a cat in and now want to sample the tagged video sections and look through the sample manually to ascertain what the FP rate is with this new data set. Note, I'm not looking to refine the model at this point, just assess it.

My null hypothesis is that the FP rate of the sample of tagged video I watch is equal to the FP rate of all the tagged video.

I think I can use this formula to determine the number of video sequences to view:

[image]

MY QUESTION:

1. My goal is to be able to say, "looking at a sample of the video, the FP rate is x given a confidence/precision of y".
2. Am I thinking through this formulation correctly? What would I use for values of p and p0? Would p be the model's reported FP rate?

I've been using this online calculator:
http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Other/1-Sample-Binomial